# Why first and last inline-block items taking height at bottom not top?

Tags: css

Why first and last inline-block items taking height at bottom not top?

**Live example** : http://dabblet.com/gist/3526764

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="slider-previous">previous</a>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/1" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/2" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/3" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/4" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/5" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/6" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/7" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/81/61/city/8" alt="">
<a href="#" class="slider-next">Next</a>
```

**CSS**

```
img {display:inline-block;}
.slider-previous {text-indent:-99999px;background: url(https://www.entropay.com/sites/entropay.com/themes/entropay_c/images/icons/arrow_icon.png) no-repeat #eee;height: 81px;width: 20px;;display:inline-block;}
.slider-next {text-indent:-99999px;background: url(https://www.entropay.com/sites/entropay.com/themes/entropay_c/images/icons/arrow_icon.png) no-repeat #eee;height: 81px;width: 20px;;display:inline-block; }
```

I want to make the arrow vertical aligned to the images. is it not possible without negative `margin-top` or `float`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is due to the lackness of a `vertical-align` defined for the images

try to add

```
img {
   vertical-align: bottom
}
```

Example dabblet: http://dabblet.com/gist/3526905

Comment: +1 Yes `vertical-align: middle` did the thing i wanted. but it's strange that vertical-align is affecting the position of box, outisde. I thought it only effects items inside box.

Comment: with `middle` I see your links a bit messed on Firefox 15. So I thought you want to use `bottom`. Change it anyway as you prefer

Comment: No it's working in firefox. I want in midle but it's going to bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
.slider-previous {text-indent:-99999px;background: url(https://www.entropay.com/sites/entropay.com/themes/entropay_c/images/icons/arrow_icon.png) no-repeat left center #eee;height: 81px;width: 20px;;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}
.slider-next {text-indent:-99999px;background: url(https://www.entropay.com/sites/entropay.com/themes/entropay_c/images/icons/arrow_icon.png) no-repeat left center #eee;height: 81px;width: 20px;;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}
```

should do the trick?

Comment: I was testing with firebug, seems like that website is slightly strange :)